# Java value of if statements

Tags: java, boolean

In Java can I return a boolean value with the following:

```
public boolean areBothEven(int i, int j) {
    return (i%2 == 0 && j%2 == 0);
}
```

Or do I need to surround the statement with an if and then return true and false appropriately?

Comment: Yes.. thats perfectly acceptable code.

Comment: It would have taken you 0.0001 seconds to answer this question yourself... Did you ran the code and something went wrong?

Comment: @pek The real code is more complex than my example.  I wanted to check that I wasn't assuming too much of the language in order to track down where the problem was coming from.

Comment: You don't even need the outer parentheses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, in fact doing stuff like `return xxx ? true : false;` or `if (xxx) return true; else return false;` is generally considered redundant and therefore bad style. In your case, you might even speed things up slightly by avoiding the `&&` (which may incur a branch mis-prediction):

```
return (i | j)%2 == 0;
```

Comment: @Multiplexer: I don't think bit operations on integers are much readable code.

Comment: I dont think thats more readable at all. Maybe because I've never been a 'low level' coder down amongst the bits, but bitwise operations involve thinking, wheras the original is easy.

Comment: @Thilo, @Visage: Agreed. I wouldn't suggest for a moment that this is the most readable solution, but I consider it perfectly acceptable when it is the only bit of code you have to read inside a function called `areBothEven`. Though, I would prefer the name `bothAreEven`. Predicates should read like positive assertions, so that statements like `if (bothAreEven(x, y)) ...` read more naturally.

Answer (score 4):

The expression is of boolean type, and is therefore suitable to be returned. You do not need to use an if statement.

Comment: Just to clarify @Visage's answer - "Yes, you can do the return you are doing, No, you do not need to do the if" :)

Answer (score -1):

The syntax is correct. But, zero is neither even nor odd, isn't it?
So, may be

```
return i !=0 && j !=0 && i%2 == 0 && j%2 == 0;
```

Comment: I feel this is same as what the question is. But why to make the things complex. Anyways i%2 == 0 if i is even or i is 0. There is no second thought to add the conditions.

Comment: Zero is neither even nor odd??? How's that? Of course, zero is even. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero